# Mocha test fails even if the result is correct

Tags: javascript, node.js, mocha.js

I am doing a javascript test and I don't know why this fails because all my tests return the right results.

**this is my app.js**

```
module.exports = function (array){
    var firstBigNumber = 0;
  var secondBigNumber = 0;

    if(array.length === 0) return 0;

      for(var index = 0; index < array.length; index++){

        if(parseInt(array[index]) === array[index]){
                if(array[index] > 0){
                if(array[index] > firstBigNumber){
                    secondBigNumber = firstBigNumber;
                    firstBigNumber = array[index];
                }else if (array[index] > secondBigNumber) {
                            secondBigNumber = array[index];
                    }
             } 
         }
         else{
                        secondBigNumber = 0;
                    firstBigNumber = 0;
         }
        }
    return [firstBigNumber,secondBigNumber];
}
```

**An this are my tests**

```
    const assert = require('assert');
const app = require('../app');

describe('App', function() {
  describe('SimpleTest2', function(){
      it('Empty array should return 0', function(){
          var array = [];
          let result = app(array);
          assert.equal(result,0);
      });
      it('Ignore float elements', function(){
        var array = [1.2, 2, 3];
        assert.equal(app(array),[3,2]);
      });
      it('Ignores non-numerical values in array', function(){
        var array = ['hei', 2, 3, 4, false];
        assert.equal(app(array),[4,3]);
      });
```

The error that I receive is Assertion Error [ERR_Asertion].
The are some of my errors I am getting:

[image]
[image]

Comment: You should use `assert.deepStrictEqual()` instead of `assert.equal()`: https://nodejs.org/api/assert.html#assert_assert_deepstrictequal_actual_expected_message

Comment: Yes it worked, thank you

Answer (score 2):

This is likely happening because `[ 3, 2 ] == [ 3, 2 ] = false`. (Welcome to javascript)

I think what you are looking for is something similiar to chais array equality.
Here's what I found:

try .eql or .deepEql instead of .equal. I was able to get expected results then.

Check out http://www.chaijs.com/api/bdd/#arguments-section - It's chai but a really good reference.

Comment: The rather `funny` side of javascript. Sarcasm intended.